# Merge [intellij] and [idea] into [intellij-idea]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

As you can see, most of the questions tagged [idea](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/idea) are also tagged [intellij](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/intellij). Also, the full name of the IDE is IntelliJ IDEA. The two tags should be merged. Also, the one other question tagged [idea](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/idea) misuses the tag in my opinion.

Comment: Most is an overstatement (with only 3 questions). Would suggest for [idea] to be deleted altogether, although the lack of a Wiki for both entries doesn't allow me to ascertain if they are indeed related, having no practice with that software..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that it's also named [intellij-idea](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) on Stack Overflow, I agree with the proposal.

Comment: @gparyani: I can do it, I'm just waiting for someone to complain ;D

Comment: You've performed the merge. Can you edit your answer?